# Create document set with REST API in SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I'm looking for a way to create a ***document set*** in my document library from within `SPFx web part`. I'm using `@microsoft/sp-http` module to create HTTP requests.

Do I need to manually create some content types inside SP?

How can I determine *content type ID* of the *document set*?

What data do I need to put in the head and body of the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make 2 HTTP requests to get it working.

1st request will get the content type Id of the document set content type present in the SharePoint document library.

2nd will make use of the content type id and then post the payload containing document set name and other necessary properties to the doc lib which will create the document set.

If you already know the content type id or you are sure that it wont change, then you can skip and "hard-code" it in your code.

The code to create it is as below, do make the changes as necessary as per your list names :

```
let ctEndpointUrl = `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/contenttypes?$select=Id&$filter=Name eq 'Document Set'`
this.context.spHttpClient.get(ctEndpointUrl,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
          'odata-version': ''
        }
      }).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json();
      }).then(ct => {

        // path of the SharePoint list
        let listUrl = `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/Shared Documents`;

        //name of the document set that you want to create
        let documentSetname = "DocumentSetName101";

        // content type id of Document set present in sharepoint list
        // you can hard-code this and skip the above HTTP request if you know the content type id before hand
        let contentTypeId = ct.d.results[0]["Id"]["StringValue"];

        let options: ISPHttpClientOptions = { 
          method: "POST", 
          body: JSON.stringify(
            { 'Title' : documentSetname , 'Path' : listUrl }), 
          headers: 
            { "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
              "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
              "slug": `${listUrl}/${documentSetname}|${contentTypeId}` 
            } 
          };

          // using the old _vti_bin/listdata.svc endpoint which expects the list's display name
          this.context.spHttpClient.post(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Documents`,
          SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, options).then((d:SPHttpClientResponse) => {
            d.json().then(res => {
              // success
              console.log(res);
            })                
          }).catch(e => {
            // error
            console.log(e);
          });
});
```

References - [Creating document sets using PnP JS](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/issues/332)

[Create document set using REST](https://julieturner.net/2016/11/create-sharepoint-document-set-and-set-metadata-using-rest/)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out soon and let you know. Do you know if I'm able to achieve the same thing using `@pnp/js` library?

Comment: no, its not supported at the moment because of SharePoint's own limitation unfortunately

Comment: Thank you @Gautam the request is working. If I add custom columns to my doc set content type, can I just put their values in request body as it is now for Title and Path?

Comment: I guess should work, haven't tried it though. Just ensure that you are using the correct column internal names

Comment: The solution worked great, thanks! I have problem uploading files to newly created doc set. Following URL doesn't seem to be correct, itgives me error 400: `${siteUrl}/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('${listTitle}')/${docSetName}/Files/Add(url='${file.name}', overwrite=true)`

Comment: can you ask this as a separate question ?

Comment: I managed to resolve it using `getFolderByServerRelativeUrl()` instead of `getBytitle()`. Thank you.

Comment: @GautamSheth Can we access Document sets in Sharepoint online using Graph Api

Comment: Hi, do you know how to handle if the documentSetname contains non ascii characters? Becouse it is thwrowing me an error: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Value is not a valid ByteString."

Comment: What imports are required for this code to work ?

Comment: Just the standard imports as sphttpclient, sphttpclientoptions and Isphttpclientoptions from Microsoft/sp-http

Comment: @JarekDanielak with PnP you can create a new folder and set its content type to your Document Set, like [this](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/folders/#create-a-folder-with-custom-content-type). You can get the Document Set ContentTypeId with [this](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/folders/#create-a-folder-with-custom-content-type)